# Continuous function on the unit interval to itself

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

We know that if $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ is continuous then $f$ has a fixed point (that is, there exists a $c\in [0,1]$ such that $f(c)=c$). Geometrically, we essentially have to prove that $f$ intersects the line $y=x$ at some point inside the box $[0,1]\times [0,1]$. However, when we prove this, we consider the new function $g(x)=f(x)-x$ and prove that $g$ intersects the $x$-axis at some point of $[0,1]$. I'm just wondering why instead of directly proving that $f$ crosses the line $y=x$, we prove $g$ crosses the $x$-axis. Any insight into this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it just  a "clockwise 45 degree" rotation of the problem? In some sense, rotating the line $x=y$ , and the graph of the function $f$, $45$ degrees clockwise, result in the line $y=0$ and the graph of the function $g$. That's why showing that the graph of $g$ intersects $y=0$ is equivalent to showing that the graph of $f$ intersects $y=x$. Having said that, the proof that $f$ intersects the line $x=y$ can be made independent of $g$ : instead, you'll just have to carry out the argument for Bolzano's theorem (or the Intermediate value theorem) in this context.

Comment: The reason why one uses $g$ instead of $f$, is , from the analytic point of view, a "reduction" argument : one provides an argument  to prove that a continuous function which takes both positive and negative values on an interval, must take the value zero as well, and then tries to reduce every possibly similar problem, to this problem. That is why $f$ was brought to $g$ : $g$ was chosen so that solving the "reduced" problem for $g$  is equivalent to solving the actual problem for $f$.

Comment: Because we can then use intermediate value theorem?

Comment: Thanks to both @TeresaLisbon and Arctic Char. Yes,looks the argument can be carried out to $f$ without introducing $g$. Looks introduction of $g$ makes it little more simpler. I was actually wondering if there was something deeper which is also related to some advanced topics.

Comment: @Ashok While I praise your intention (+1), I don't see anything very interesting in the connection between $f$ and $g$, personally, beyond what I said, of course.